# can not open VS2005 solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a visual studio 2005 solution with many projects. Yesterday I was able to open it normally. Today, when I double click on it, I get the following error message:

The selected file is a Visual Studio solution file, but was created by a newer version of Visual Studio and can not be opened.

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like somebody opened and converted your solution using a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Have any of the projects in your solution been edited with VS2008 or VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you, or someone, opened the file in VS 2008/2010. The solution file has been upgraded. You can create a new solution, add the projects, of course in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I right clicked on sln file and used Visual studio version selector to open the file and it was successful.